# JSON Format is off

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

The keys and values are separated in the Json object that I get from an api call. I have tried finding a solution It looks like the following:

```
{
  "range": "'1'!A1:AM243",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": 
    [
      "DeptID",
      "DeptDescr",
      "VP Area",
      "VP Descr",
      "HR Category",
      "Employee Relations1",
      "ER1Title",
      "ER1Phone",
      "ER1Email",
      "Employee Relations2",
      "ER2Title",
      "ER2Phone",
      "ER2Email",
      "Compensation1",
      "Comp1Title",
      "Comp1Phone",
      "Comp1Email",
      "Compensation2",
      "Comp2Title",
      "Comp2Phone",
      "Comp2Email",
      "Employment1",
      "E1Title",
      "E1Phone",
      "E1Email",
      "Employment2",
      "E2Title",
      "E2Phone",
      "E2Email",
      "Employee Pay Services1",
      "EPS1Title",
      "EPS1Phone",
      "EPS1Email",
      "Employee Pay Services2",
      "EPS2Title",
      "EPS2Phone",
      "EPS2Email"
    ],
    [
      "20734",
      "Academic Success Centers",
      "VES",
      "VP Enroll Mgmt & Student Aff",
      "Administrative",
      "Brian Schmidt",
      "  Employee Relations Consultant",
      "(928)523-6139",
      "Brian.Schmidt@nau.edu",
      "Marcia Warden",
      "Assistant Director, Employee Relations",
      "(928)523-9624",
      "Marcia.Warden@nau.edu",
      "Nicole Christian",
      "Employment & Compensation Analyst",
      "(928)523-6127",
      " Nicole.Christian@nau.edu",
      "Cathy Speirs",
      "Associate Director",
      "(928)523-6136",
      "Cathy.Speirs@nau.edu",
      "Nicole Christian",
      "Employment & Compensation Analyst",
      "(928)523-6127",
      " Nicole.Christian@nau.edu",
      "Cathy Speirs",
      "Associate Director",
      "(928)523-6136",
      "Cathy.Speirs@nau.edu",
      "Katherine Kurpierz",
      "Payroll Specialist",
      "(928)523-6129",
      "Katherine.Kurpierz@nau.edu",
      "Cheryl Brothers",
      "Assistant Director - HR Payroll Services",
      "(928)523-6085",
      "Cheryl.Brothers@nau.edu"
    ], etc.
```

But I need it to look like:

```
[  
 {  
   "DeptID": 20734,  
   "DeptDescr": "Academic Success Centers",  
   "VP Area": "VES",  
   "VP Descr": "VP Enroll Mgmt & Student Aff",  
   "HR Category": "Administrative",  
   "Employee Relations1": "Brian Schmidt",  
   "Employee Relations2": "Marcia Warden",  
   "Compensation1": "Nicole Christian",  
   "Compensation2": "Cathy Speirs",  
   "Employment1": "Nicole Christian",  
   "Employment3": "Cathy Speirs",  
"Employee Pay Services1": "Katherine Kurpierz",  
   "Employee Pay Services2": "Cheryl Brothers"  
 },etc
```

I am trying to use the data to populate a drop down using javascript and ajax. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The JSON you provided is not valid. Can you make sure its format is valid?

Comment: That's a really unfortunately designed API response, but it looks like the first array contains the key names, the second array contains the corresponding values, in the same order.  Have you tried just matching those up?

Comment: (I assume "values" is actually an array containing the two arrays shown here and you've just accidentally left out the wrapping array when posing it  here? If that's not the case please post the actual JSON you're dealing with, as well as code representing your attempt to solve the problem; simply asking people to do the work for you is not generally how things here are supposed to work.)

Comment: This is not a valid json, try to run it and you will get `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,",`  what @leosteffen says is right.  it should be `values:[], data:[]` or somthing like that. are you sure that this is what you get from the api?

Comment: OP,  are you sure you should be putting names, emails, and phone numbers in an actual stack overflow post like this?

Comment: I tried to edit it for him, and can't save the edit because the question has "too much code"

Answer (score 0):

The object your API returns is not a valid JSON. Was that API made by you or can you get that fixed somehow?

There are 2 things you could do to make it work
-**One** is change it to return exactly what you want;
-**Two** is to fix what it returns so that it is a valid JSON;

Going for what is wrong with the file you initially posted, let's remove the contents of the arrays so it's easier to spot the problem:

Your original data looks roughly like this:

```
{ "range": "'1'!A1:AM243",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [],[]
}
```

To be valid you would need it to look like this:

```
{ "range": "'1'!A1:AM243",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": {
    "keys": [],
    "data": [],
  }
}
```

Notice that I wrapped the two arrays of "values" with { } because it has to be an object if you want it to contain two arrays in it.
Then I gave each array a key with which you can call them. With that you'd be able to get what you want from your "values", so that for each item in the "keys" array you have something in that "data" array.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well let's have a look;

Suppose this is a short version of the response data you got:

```
var res = `
{
    "range": "'1'!A1:AM243",
    "majorDimension": "ROWS",
    "values": [
        "DeptID",
        "DeptDescr",
        "VP Area"
    ],
    [
        "20734",
        "Academic Success Centers",
        "VES"
    ],
    [
        "345543",
        "Academic Fails Centers",
        "OK"
    ]
}
`;
```

As we can see by the first data, looks like a dump from a spreadsheet of sorts, and someone maybe scripted a way to export this data in a JSON-ish way. The values "Array" are the rows of this "spreadsheet".

We will clean it up, and get only the chunks that looks like `["value", "another value", "etc"]`

```
// clean tabs and returns
res = res.replace(/\t/g, '').replace(/\n/g, '');
// get the array-ish chunks
rows = res.match(/\[(((["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\4.)*?\3),*)+\]/gm)
```

now let's make them real arrays:

```
var data = rows.map(function (row) {
  return JSON.parse(row);
});
```

Now we have an array of arrays of strings. that means, an array of "rows" that contains the values of the "cells". The first one looks like the header row (the one with the names of the fields)

Lets make objects using each row of data except the first one. The first will serve us as the keys (we match the position (index) of the value from rows[n] from the value on rows[0] to get a key-value pair)

```
// Here we will define an object to store data
var data_object = { values: [] };

// for each row except the first
for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  var my_data = {};
  //for each element of this row
  for(var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
    my_data[data[0][j]] = data[i][j];
  }
  data_object.values.push(my_data);
}
```

We have our object, let's suppose you need it in JSON format now:

```
var json_data = JSON.stringify(data_object);
// let's look what we have here
console.log('json_data:', json_data);
```

We will look at something like this as a result:

```
json_data: {"values":[{"DeptID":"20734","DeptDescr":"Academic Success Centers","VP Area":"VES"},{"DeptID":"345543","DeptDescr":"Academic Fails Centers","VP Area":"OK"}]}
```

NOW A WARNING:

This is what you DON'T want to do if you can fix the API you are getting this data from first. If any inconsistency appears, things will break. and in this example i'm not managing any edge case or exception, neither checking boundaries of arrays or wrapping things in try-catch blocks.